# Counting possible permutations where placements yield different values

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Imagine you have 8 colored squares, say, 2 red, 2 blue, 2 green, 2 yellow.  You can permute these in 
$$\frac{8!}{2^4} = 2520$$
unique ways.  This can similarly be counted as combinations where each color's position is selected independently, 
$$\binom{8}{2}\cdot \binom{6}{2} \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{2}{2} = 2520.$$
(Maybe this is a more helpful way to think about it)??  However, also imagine that each position in the order is worth a dollar amount, say, 9/7/6/5/4/3/2/1.

1) How many unique ways can each color earn money? In other words, consider the two permutations: RBYGGBRY and BGRRYYGB.  These orders yield the same values for each color.  Red = 11 in both, Blue = 10 in both, Green = 9 in both and Yellow = 7 in both.  How do I exclude counting these from the 2520? Note: I would MUCH PREFER A HINT, rather than just telling me the solution.  I've tried working with the different possible sums, but keep getting nowhere.  (I've also tried creating an algorithm to check all of the 8! permutations and find the ones that yield unique values for each color.  My computer did not like this very much - I'm still working on an algorithm that only checks the 2520 unique permutations to make it a little more manageable).

The question I'm currently more interested in, however, is:

2) If Red is placed in given positions, say 1st and 5th.  What is the probability that another color earns more or equal money than red.  So far, I've figured that if red is placed, then there are 6 more spots remaining and we can repeat as above to get, 
$$\frac{6!}{2^3} = 90$$
total permutations remaining.  But to calculate theoretical probability, I need to divide this from the number of ways the desired event can occur.  This is what I'm unsure of how to count.

In the case of red placed in 1st and 5th positions, red totals 13 dollars.  There is then only one other way a color can be worth at least 13 dollars: being placed in the 2nd and 3rd position.  Since there are 3 colors, I believe this means there is a 
$$\frac{\binom{3}{1} \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{2}{2}}{90} = \frac{18}{90} = 20\%$$
 probability that red won't be worth the most.  Here the $\binom{3}{1}$ is to pick a color from Green, Blue, or Yellow to fill the 2nd / 3rd slots and the $\binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{2}{2}$ counts the number of ways the remaining two colors can be distributed into the remaining 4 slots. For some reason, I'm second guessing myself - is this a correct way to approach this?

I've tried to write an algorithm that keeps a tally for every combination where the second placed color exceeds red's total.  Assuming that algorithm works correctly (it's definitely possible it does not in actuality), then my expression for the probability that red is worth the most, given red's placement would be $P = 1 - \frac{18 \cdot (\text{tally})}{90}$?

Update: I updated my algorithm for question 1 to be much more efficient and got 1448 unique outcomes.  It's tough to check if this is correct though because there isn't really a small case to check it on that works the same.  Can anyone 2nd this answer?

Comment: re: question 2: since 2nd+3rd is the only other viable pair, this is really easy.  Some color has to occupy 2nd.  Its partner has 5 places to go (all but 1st, 2nd, 5th), so prob that it occupies 3rd is $\frac15$.  :)  If there are more viable pairs you need more general counting methods, but for this particular case, I hope this shows you don't have to second-guess yourself.

Comment: Your count of $1448$ unique outcomes is correct for the given positional values. I used a simple anagram routine to generate all valid permutations, and counted those with a scoring result not previously encountered.

Comment: @DanielMathias - thanks you! I did the same, though I'm more of a beginner at programming so it wasn't so simple for me at first - apparently I did get it though.